# How to Login to Magento using SSH?

Tags: magento, ssh, terminal, magento2

i'm trying to login to magento using ssh, but unsure which line of code to type in the terminal. I tried ssh -lroot ip address, unfortuntately it's not wokring. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For most cases:

```
ssh user@example.com
```

For non standard port:

```
ssh -p 2222 user@example.com
```

In case you have a "@" symbol in user name:

```
ssh -l user@example.com example.com
```